# How to get the number of newlines in a cell value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets assume I have an imaginary table named `bookInfo`, which contains the following values:

```
|id   |book_name   |description   |
-----------------------------------
|1    |book 1      |dummy         |
|2    |book 2      |harry         |
|     |            |potter        |
|     |            |Part 2        |
|3    |...
```

The cell value for the `description` column of the second record (`id = 2`) contains multiple newline character sequences between the "harry" and "potter" keywords like so:

```
harry \n potter \n part 2
```

Is there a way to count the number of newline characters in the `description` column, e.g. do something like the following:

```
SELECT (count new line)description FROM bookInfo WHERE id=2;
```

The prior query should return an integer value of `2`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the SQL-standard `position` function for this:

```
craig=> SELECT position( E'\r' in E'abc\rdef\rghi' );
 position 
----------
        4
(1 row)
```

or:

```
craig=> SELECT position( chr(13) in E'abc\rdef\rghi' );
 position 
----------
        4
(1 row)
```

Comment: `position` will return the position of the first occurrence of the new line character **not** their count

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the length of the string with newline and with out.

```
SELECT (LENGTH(description) - LENGTH(REPLACE(description, '\n', '')) FROM `bookinfo`
```

### Trimmed count

If you want to count only the newlines in between (without leading and trailing newlines) you can trim them first

```
SELECT (LENGTH(TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM description)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM description), '\n', ''))) FROM `bookinfo`
```

Comment: I prefer this one because it seems like REPLACE will have performance advantages over REGEX_REPLACE, and I have a big table.

Comment: You need to use CHR(10) instead of '/n', see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028908/postgresql-newline-character

Answer (score 4):

One simple way:

```
SELECT length(regexp_replace(your_field, E'[^\\n]', '', 'g')) from your_table
```

Note: `position()` find the first occurrence and return its position.

Answer (score -1):

you may look for carriage return by finding char(13) in your table field.

```
select * from bookinfo where CHARINDEX(char(13),description)<>0
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: `CHARINDEX` doesn't appear to be supported by PostgreSQL, so no, not so much.