# PostgreSQL newline character

Tags: string, postgresql, newline

How to use `newline character` in `PostgreSQL`?

This is an incorrect script from my experiment:

```
select 'test line 1'||'\n'||'test line 2';
```

I want the `sql editor` display this result from my script above:

```
test line 1
test line 2
```

But unfortunately I just get this result from my script when I run it in sql editor:

```
test line 1 test line 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert new line in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949768/how-to-insert-new-line-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Elad, my question is about "select"  query. to read data in table   no insert "create" . the answer from a_horse_with_no_name is enough to solve me problem now.

Comment: the answer there `You are missing e right before new line literal` is the same answer as given to you here.

Comment: your mean in this part "'||'\n'||'", in my code?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

The backslash has no special meaning in SQL, so `'\n'` is a backslash followed by the character `n`

To use "escape sequences" in a string literal you need to use an ["extended" constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE):

```
select 'test line 1'||E'\n'||'test line 2';
```

Another option is to use the `chr()` function:

```
select 'test line 1'||chr(10)||'test line 2';
```

Or simply put the newline in the string constant:

```
select 'test line 1
test line 2';
```

---

Whether or not this is actually *displayed* as two lines in your SQL client, depends on your SQL client.

---

UPDATE: a good answer from @thedayturns, where you can have a simpler query:

```
select E'test line 1\ntest line 2';
```

Comment: It's a little silly to only extend the newline character part of the string, right? You could just do `E'test line 1\ntest line 2'`

Comment: @thedayturns Thanks. I successfully used your answer to query a column containing serialized data (to be specific YAML string like `{ my_data: [ { data_type: 'MyType', data_id: 113 } ] }`). For e.g. `select * from table_name where column_name = E'---\n:my_data:\n- :data_type: MyType\n  :data_id: 113\n'`

Comment: What does the preceeding `E` in `E'test line 1\ntest line 2'` do? That ended up being my fix.

Comment: @Sampson: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search if a jsonb contains \n this works

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column ~ '^.*\\n.*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use [dollar-quoted strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE). Everything included pairs of dollar signs is treated as a string literal. You can just say

```
select $$test line 1
test line 2$$
```