# PostgreSql not splitting string by new line

Tags: postgresql

I can't make PostgreSql split a string into multiple strings based on newline characters. I have tried splitting by: \n, \r, \r\n. But it's not working!

Not working code:

```
SELECT string_to_array('Test1
Test2', '\r\n')
```

Working code (newline character copied directly from text, but it is displayed as invisible \r\n or CRLF):

```
SELECT string_to_array('Test1
    Test2', '
')
```

Initial data - a table, the content of which is imported from a .csv file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After a quick search for "Postgresql Newline character", I've found
[PostgreSQL newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028908/postgresql-newline-character)

Copied Answer:

> the backslash has no special meaning in SQL, so '\n' is a backslash followed by the character n
> To use "escape sequences" in a string literal you need to use an ["extended" constant:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE)

In your case

```sql
SELECT string_to_array('Test1
Test2', E'\n')
```

Result

| string_to_array |
| --- |
| {Test1,Test2} |