# What the best way to store the format of a complex string, in a format table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working on the design of a database that will store each component of an address in separate fields (street number, street name, city…)

I would like to have a tb_address_format table, that stores for each country the order in which the elements should be arranged to output a valid postal address.

I am thinking something like:

```
+──────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
| country  | address_format                                                |
+──────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
| us       | FORMAT('%s\n%s %s\t%s', street, city, province, postal_code)  |
| de       | FORMAT('%s\n%s %s', street, postal_code, city)                |
|          |                                                               |
|          |                                                               |
+──────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
```

Asking this question makes me realise I can store these two informations in two different fields:

- the format string
- the list of fields

like so:

```
+──────────+──────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────+
| country  | format_string    | list_of_fields                       |
+──────────+──────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────+
| us       | '%s\n%s %s\t%s'  | street, city, province, postal_code  |
| de       | '%s\n%s %s'      | street, postal_code, city            |
+──────────+──────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────+
```

What else can I do to improve this design and its security?

EDIT 1: I am trying to evaluate the result directly in a calculated field, in SQL. That would mean also using some extended constant like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028908/postgresql-newline-character), on how to transform \n into a new line.

EDIT 2: street, city, province, postal_code are indeed table columns. I was first thinking about storing them as a VARCHAR and then evaluating the result.

Following the hint from @Bergi in the comment below about using pg_catalog, is it possible / desirable to store an array where each item references the pg_catalog.pg_attribute table?

EDIT 3: some code to play with

```sql
CREATE TABLE tb_address(
city varchar,
street varchar,
postal_code varchar, 
county varchar,
state varchar,
country varchar);

CREATE TABLE tb_address_format(
country varchar,
address_format varchar,
list_of_fields text ARRAY);

INSERT INTO tb_address(
street, city, county, state, postal_code, country
)
VALUES
('150 5th Ave', 'New York', NULL, 'NY', '10011', 'USA'),
('Holzgasse 14', 'Köln', NULL, NULL, '50676', 'Germany');

INSERT INTO tb_address_format(
  country, address_format, list_of_fields
)
VALUES
('USA', '%s\n%s %s %s', '{"street", "city", "state", "postal_code"}'),
('Germany', '%s\n%s %s\n\n%s', '{"street", "postal_code", "city", "country"}');
```

Expected result: the calc_formatted column is a SQL calculated column.

```
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+
| street       | city     | postal_code | state | country | calc_formatted                      |
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+
| 150 5th Ave  | New York | 10011       | NY    | USA     | 150 5th Ave\nNew York NY 10011\nUSA |
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Holzgasse 14 | Köln     | 50676       |       | Germany | Holzgasse 14\n50676 Köln\nGermany   |
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The second option is less language dependent so maybe a bit better

Comment: Do you want to process that "format function" in SQL or in your application?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I was thinking using the FORMAT function of Postgresql, so as to evaluate the result in a calculated field which would be much faster than on the application layer.

Comment: Are those table columns? You could potentially use a foreign key to [`pg_catalog.pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/catalog-pg-attribute.html).

Comment: @Bergi - yes inded, those are table columns. I updated my question.

Comment: Actually I guess the foreign key isn't that a good idea. All it would achieve is nicer metaprogramming/schema introspection and better consistency guarantees for schema changes (like column renames). But honestly, how often is the schema of `tb_address` going to change, and does that need special precautions? I guess you're much better off with a simple `CHECK` constraint that enumerates the allowed values. Sorry for sending you off in the wrong direction.

Comment: "*I can store these two informations in two different fields*" - you could, but I don't think that's necessary. Unless you want to use dynamic SQL (generating the `FORMAT` expression) in PL/pgSQL, *and* unless you have common queries that e.g. print only American addresses or only German addresses, you most likely need a query that can handle all columns anyway. It might be simpler to store the format in a string like `'$street\n$postal_code $city'` and evaluate it using search&replace, e.g. `replace(replace(format, '$street', street), '$postal_code', postal_code) …`.

Comment: Alternatively, use an `ARRAY['street', '\n', 'postal_code', ' ', 'city']` for the template, where you can validate that each element is either a column name or whitespace (or whatever validation you need/want). Or even just JSON `[{"col": "street"}, {"literal": "\n"}, {"col": "postal_code"}, {"literal": " "}, {"column": "city"}]` which has no restrictions on the literal parts and doesn't need escaping. To format these templates, iterate over the array, replace column refs by the respective value and literals by themselves, then aggregate back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

`list_of_fields` - JSONB (indexes, functions, readable, etc)

To ensure consistency use one of JSON schema implementations:
https://github.com/supabase/pg_jsonschema#prior-art

[Blog post](https://supabase.com/blog/pg-jsonschema-a-postgres-extension-for-json-validation)

**UPD**

- [DB level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)
- App level

```
>>> import json_str
>>> json_str = '{"city": "par", "street": "str", "postal_code": 123}'
>>> address = json.loads(json_str)
>>> print(address)
{'city': 'par', 'street': 'str', 'postal_code': 123}
>>> print(address['city'])
par
```

**UPD 1: CSV**

DB:

```
+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| country | headers                 | values                |
+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| us      | city,street,postal_code | cty,"some street",123 |
+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Python

```py
import csv
headers = next(csv.reader(['city,street,postal_code']))
values = next(csv.reader(['cty,"some street",123']))
address = dict(zip(headers, values))
print(address)
# {'city': 'cty', 'street': 'some street', 'postal_code': '123'}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. sorry, I am more a Python guy than a Javascript guy. From what I understand of the blog post, this enables to output a JSON schema. Could you elaborate on how I can use this technique to output a plain string?

Comment: @LionelHamayon There's no JavaScript in that blog post?

Comment: In this context, consider json as a serialized object. Look at update.

Comment: @cetver I don't see how storing an address as a JSON document helps you with formatting the address parts into a string

Comment: imho, the best way to store a complex string is a JSON, without any raw formats

Comment: @cetver the string itself is rather simple, where I am struggling is how I can make its format dynamic by outputting directly from the db different variations from the same subparts, and how to store these variations instructions.

Comment: Look at UPD 1: CSV

Comment: @cetver: sorry for the misleading expected result, and thank you for the elegant Python solution. I am trying to achieve this result in a SQL calculated column.